# Where do I find purely functional open source projects written in Scala?

Tags: scala, open-source, functional-programming

I'm looking for open source projects that are written in Scala in a purely functional style, i.e. that don't use `var`s or mutable data structures (or that use them as litte as necessary). I would prefer applications over frameworks and libraries because I want to see how functional objects are "glued together".

Note that this question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/2135966/460387 but the focus here is the purley functional style of the projects.

Comment: It might be a good idea to go to something like launchpad an filter by language, however finding something purely functional may be hard - when working on a large project it's often better to be pragmatic and use the best programming style for the task at hand. As most projects contain a variety of tasks this often leads to a range of styles. Although in python not scala I often mix purely functional code with OO code in real projects.

Comment: That said it is technically possible to write equivilent code functionally, and many might describe OO as syntactic sugar. I think you might have best luck looking for academic work rather than real-world projects. If it has to be real-world it's most likely to be a liibrary.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning to use the best style for the task at hand but to make a well considered decision I need to know the alternatives. Currently I just don't know them and would like to learn from existing projects that only (or mostly) use functional concepts. Maybe I should learn to write applications in Haskell first and then come back to Scala.

Comment: Actually, I was *almost* going to write that as an answer, except I was just going to suggest *reading* Haskell apps :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a library, but I think [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/) is an excellent example of pure functional style in Scala.

Comment: +1. Scalaz is *the* canonical example of (typed) functional programming in Scala, not just in the "immutable, pure and referentially transparent" sense, but also because of the heavy use of Typeful Programming and Type-Driven Design and equational reasoning as well as heavily leaning on Type Theory and Category Theory. (In some older versions they took Typeful Programming so far as to not even give the methods pronouncable names, just weird-looking Unicode symbols, because they wanted to emphasize the fact that in a well-designed library, all you need to know is already in the types.)

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at [specs2](http://specs2.org). It is mostly functional as explained [here](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Philosophy.html), except for:

- the use of 1 mutable variable to give some DSL flexibility in one place
- the use of exceptions (optionally) for the same reason
- outputs which are eventually using the Console or the FileSystem

Comment: Hey, I didn't know that! Nice!

Comment: I'll definitely have a look at specs2 since I'm also using it for my Scala project.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-exhaustive list of (mostly) functional applications and libraries written in Scala based on the answers to this question. Please feel free to add more projects to this list.

### Applications:

### Libraries:

- [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/) includes general functions that are not currently available in the core Scala API.
- [specs2](http://specs2.org/) is a library for writing executable software specifications.